# When you click on the button and on the picture, there should be a shift to the left by 100 pixels, but this does not happen why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

When you click on the button and on the picture, there should be a shift to the left by 100 pixels, but this does not happen why?

I try to move some elements using Jquery, but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".left").click(function() {
    let paragraphs = $("p");
    $(paragraphs[2]).animate({
      left: '100px'
    });
  })
  let images = $("img");
  $(images[1]).click(function() {
    $(images[1]).animate({
      left: "100 px"
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <div class="mega-div">
    <p>text1</p>
    <img src="images indv4/1images.png">
    <p>text2</p>
    <img src="images indv4/2images.png">
    <p>text3</p>
    <img src="images indv4/3images.png">
    <p>text4</p>
    <img src="images indv4/4images.png">
    <p>text5</p>
  </div>

  <button class="left">Сместить параграфы</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The image should have a `position` property with `relative`. Otherwise it `left` doesn't affect the element. And make sure you type your `left` values without spaces; `100 px` won't work, but `100px` will.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".left").click(function() {
    let paragraphs = $("p");
    $(paragraphs[2]).animate({
      left: '100px'
    });
  })
  let images = $("img");
  $(images[1]).click(function() {
    $(images[1]).animate({
      left: "100px"
    });
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <div class="mega-div">
    <p>text1</p>
    <img src="images indv4/1images.png">
    <p>text2</p>
    <img src="images indv4/2images.png">
    <p>text3</p>
    <img src="images indv4/3images.png">
    <p>text4</p>
    <img src="images indv4/4images.png">
    <p>text5</p>
  </div>

  <button class="left">Сместить параграфы</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Sweet. Please mark the answer as accepted so that others can benefit from your question.